# Classification using python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

```
[[ 82  32  14 ...   8 113 128]
 [  2  32  70 ...   8 113 128]
 [ 18  32  78 ...   8 113 128]
 ...
 [ 92  48 249 ... 240   7 115]
 [ 24 141  11 ... 170 176 168]
 [188 165   8 ... 203 144 128]]
```

I got this type of data and i want to classify the data and get the accuracy of them by using Python.

Comment: could you articulate a bit better? Classify what and how? Include some code so it will be easier to understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I've got a project to do for the college, Trying to Feature detection from some certain images. I've achieved detecting feauters from all images. Now i need to classify this data that i've collected by using Decision tree or any other algorithm using Python

Comment: maybe add some tags to your question to make clear which technology are you using, `scikitlearn`, ...